# getSalary() method not working

Tags: java, class

```
public class EmployeeTester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Employee e = new Employee("Harry", 5000);
    e.raiseSalary(15);
    System.out.println("New Salary" + getSalary());
    System.out.println("Hello" + getName());
  }
}
```

I am having an error when calling "getName()" and "getSalary()" above. The code is below. I am rather new to this and would appreciate any help!

```
public class Employee
{
  private String employeeName;
  private double currentSalary;
  private double byPercent;

  public Employee(String employeeName, double currentSalary)
  {

  }

  public void raiseSalary(double byPercent)
  {
    double percentDivided;  
    percentDivided = byPercent / 100.0;
    currentSalary = currentSalary + (currentSalary * percentDivided);
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return employeeName;
  } 

  public double getSalary()
  {
    return currentSalary;
  }
}
```

Comment: The constructor is empty. The fields `employeeName` and `byPercent` are not initialized.

Comment: `if (employeeName.equals("Bathsheba")) return Double.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Seriously, use a currency type for money data.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
System.out.println("New Salary" + getSalary());
System.out.println("Hello" + getName());
```

Should be

```
System.out.println("New Salary" + e.getSalary());
System.out.println("Hello" + e.getName());
```

to call the methods on the `Employee` instance `e`.

Comment: Yep, adding to that the fact that your constructor does nothing, and you should be able to fix your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is empty, you're never setting the initial employeeName and currentSalary:

```
public Employee(String employeeName, double currentSalary)
{
   this.employeeName = employeeName;
   this.currentSalary = currentSalary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell Java what object shall execute the `getSalary()` method.
Try `e.getSalary()`, same with `getName()`.

Your constructor does nothing btw. It takes variables, but you don't assign them to the object's.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is empty. The variables are not being passed the values.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the constructor taking in name and salary but not setting them to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so right at the beginning you declare 3 variables: EmployeeName, currentSalary, and byPercent. These are outside of any method. This means they are "instance fields", basically the properties of your Employee. They hold the data. You say "Employees need a name". You need to actually let the program know. In your constructor, you should rename your parameters. You don't want them to have the same name as your instance fields. So have it be "nameParameter" or something. Just not employeeName. Then in your constructor just specify `employeeName = nameParameter;` and you should be good. Do the same type of thing for the salary.